# Hello, can someone help me with this error?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, constants

I do not understand why line 21 is ok but line 25 is error?

The **error** message:

> invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Push is function in class that decleared like this:

```
template< typename Type >  
class Stack { 
    void Push(const Type& value) {
       SNode* type = new SNode();
       if (this->head != nullptr) { 
           this->head->up = temp;
       }
       temp->value = value;
       temp->up = nullptr;
       temp->down = head;
       temp->head = temp;
       num_of_elements++;
   }
};

int main() {
    Stack<int*>* stk = new Stack<int*>();
    int a = 5;
    int* x = &a;
    stk->Push(x); //this line is fine
    const int b = 5;
    const int* y = &b;
    stk->Push(y); //this line is an error
    delete stk;
    return 0;
}
```

It's look like function Push get parameter from type of "`const int * &`" , and in line 25 , i exactly sends a const pointer "`const int *`". so what is the problem?

Comment: It would help if you had a better title and you included the error message in your question.  You might also want to make the function in question not private.

Comment: Your error is thinking that `Push()` is waiting for a `const int * &`; it's waiting for a `int * const &`; a total different type (hope my answer can explain better).

Answer (score 1):

The `Push()` in line 21

```
int a = 5;
int * x = &a;
stk->Push(x);
```

where `Push()` wait for a `const Type & value` (with `Type` equal to `int *`, if I understand correctly), works because you're sending a `int *` to a method that is wainting for a compatible type, a `const Type &` that is `int * const &`.

Remember that `const` is applied on the left, on the right when there isn't nothing on the left, so `const Type &` is `Type const &` that is `int * const &`. So is a reference to a constant pointer to a not-constant integer.

When you write (`Push()` in line 25)

```
const int b = 5;
const int * y = &b;
stk->Push(y);
```

you're sending a `const int *`, that is a `int const *` (not-constant pointer to a constant integer), to a method that is waiting for a `int * const &` (a reference to a constant pointer to a not-constant integer).

The two types are incompatibles, so the error.

You can try with

```
int b = 5;
int * const y = &b;
stk->Push(y);
```

This should work.

Comment: So how can i write that so if Type is pointer, so the place that is pointerd is will be the const?

Comment: @BestMath Make it `Stack<const int*>` instead of `Stack<int*>`